What is the better way to know if the value was already used in the record previously?
I need to have a validation wherein a certain picklist value (e.g: in progress) was already selected before in the record. So basically, the "in progress' status should only be selected once in the record (can be modified via custom metadata). If I were to select it multiple times then I shouldn't be allowed.
I thought that it's not possible using the validation rule so my option is using apex.
I'm also thinking of using the history table of the object to check if the picklist value is already existing, but my concern is the limitation of history in salesforce object (the history record is deleted automatically by sf after sometime.
If I don't use the history then the other option is to create a field so I can save how many times the status has been selected so I can check if the selected value should be prevented.. but I have a lot of picklist values to prevent.. and I want to avoid creating many fields.
Is there a better way to check if the picklist value has been selected before?

You need to add a Checkbox field on the record that defaults to false and get gets set true (via apex or a record triggered flow) when the "in progress" status is first selected. If it's already set true when the "in progress" status is (re-)selected by the user, that's an error - you could detect this in an appropriate validation rule. To avoid lots of fields, you COULD mirror the picklist in a multi-select picklist field, and add selections to the latter as the user makes selections in the picklist field, then do something similar (probably in apex) to check if an option is re-selected.

Field history can be retained indefinitely:

You can select certain fields to track and show the field history in the History related list of an object. When Field Audit Trail is turned off, Salesforce retains field history data for up to 18 months, and up to 24 months via the API. If Field Audit Trail is turned on, Salesforce retains field history data until you delete it. You can delete field history data manually at any time. Field history tracking data doesn’t count against your data storage limits. (Emphasis added)

Alternatively, create a multi-select picklist to track previously used entries. Each time the field changes, check if the value was already used; if so, add and error, otherwise, add the value to the multi-select list.
As another option, you can also use a bit field. Basically, you use a number field as a collection of bits. Each bit is a flag that keeps track of something. In our use case, we can use a number field as a Long to keep track of 64 independent values, which is probably enough for your use case. The main downside so this approach is that changing the index order of the picklist values also requires the bit field to be mapped appropriately. Custom Metadata would probably be ideal to manage this mapping.
